# Does flutter have problem with exynos cpu?

Tags: flutter, dart

I write a flutter application and it is run very good on android devices but unfortunetly I test this app on 3 Samsung phones by Exynos CPU and it doesn't run well.
I test it in release mode .
is there anything that I should do with my app.
does this issue resolve with appBundle because I don't test appBundle ?
any Idea??

Comment: which version of flutter did you use?

Comment: 1.9 , I think it is the last one version

Comment: it would be helpful if you provide result of `flutter doctor -v` command in your post